# Matrix Squareroot Using Single Value Decomposition (SVD)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, svd, pseudoinverse

I'm trying to find the square root of a square matrix(real or complex) that can have complex eigenvalues and eigenvalues. The approach that I'm using requires me to first calculate the `Eigenvalues` and the `Eigenvectors`. For this purpose, I'm using LAPACK's `zgeev`. I get the correct eigens using this routine.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

by applying LAPACK's `zgeev` i get eigens as

$$eigenValues = \begin{bmatrix}2.5+1.9365i \\ 2.5-1.9365i\end{bmatrix} eigenVectors=\begin{bmatrix}-0.3873+0.5i & -0.3873-0.5i\\ 0.7746+0i&0.7746+0i\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we know that the square root of the matrix can be calculated as
$$PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$$

Where `P` is the `eigenVectors` and `D` is eigenValues.

The $P^{-1}$ is not the inverse but the `Pseudo Inverse` that I'm trying to calculate. Now to calculate the `Pseudo Inverse` of the matrix `P`, I'm using the `Single Value Decomposition`. For this purpose, I'm using LAPACK's `zgesvd` routine that returns back 3 matrices commonly known as `USV`

$$U = \begin{bmatrix}-0.5532+0.1892i & 0.7676-0.2625i \\ 0.2625+0.7676i & 0.1892+0.5532i\end{bmatrix} S=\begin{bmatrix}1.2777 \\ 0.6063\end{bmatrix} 
 \\ V = \begin{bmatrix}0.7071+0i & 0.7071+0i \\ 0.5590+0.433i & -0.5590-0.4330i\end{bmatrix}$$

**Problem:** The V matrix that comes from LAPACK contains exact values as of Matlab's SVD but the signs are different.
$$LAPACK's\_V = \begin{bmatrix}0.7071+0i & 0.7071+0i \\ 0.5590+0.433i & -0.5590-0.4330i\end{bmatrix} \\ Matlab's\_V = \begin{bmatrix}0.7071+0i & 0.7071+0i \\ 0.5590-0.433i & -0.5590+0.4330i\end{bmatrix}$$

I have tested this on python as well. I'm using Scipy's Linear Algebra module and the `V` that I get from Scipy's SVD also matches the `V` of LAPACK. Matlab's SVD is different however but the correct one as it gives me accurate results.

Now I have created the whole pipeline that calculates the `Pseudo Inverse` using `SVD` and then I can calculate the Matrix Squareroot using Python, Matlab, and Swift but due to the sign ambiguity in this only matrix `V`, my results become inconsistent in Python and Swift. But for Matlab, if I follow the exact steps, I get the perfect square root. I have done multiple tests and have come to the conclusion that the root cause of incorrect results is the sign problem in matrix `V` of Scipy or Swift(LAPACK).

**Questions**

1. Please guide me that why is `V` different? As far as my knowledge goes, Matlab also uses LAPACK at the backend.
2. What is the most straightforward way to fix this issue?
3. Is there any other approach to calculate matrix square root or at least the Pseudo Inverse?

I'm very close to solve this square root problem. I just need to fix `V`.

Comment: I would recommend these most widely used C++ vectors/matrix/linear algebra libraries. It will also cover their benefits and cost tradeoffs. Please Visit [Linear Algebra Libraries Cost Trade-off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1380432/10413749).

Comment: If you already have access to matlab then it has a built-in function `pinv` which computes the pseudoinverse. Or it also has built-in functionality to compute matrix powers.

Comment: @Rammus I have to develop this algorithm in Swift Language where I don't have access to these methods. I'm using Python and Matlab just for the development and experimentation of this algorithm so I can replicate it on Swift Language.

Comment: @Moo Because the Squareroot of a matrix can be calculated as `P*D^(1/2)*P^(-1)`. That is why I require pseudo inverse.

Comment: @Moo in my case it is not necessary that P will always be a Singular Matrix. This is why I cannot use a simple inverse. I have to take the Pseudo Inverse. Otherwise, the algorithm may crash or a divide by zero can occur. Pseudo Inverse is a must requirement.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I thought you wanted it for that single matrix, but you want to generalize this.

Comment: @Moo Yes exactly. And I should also mention that I don't have a defined Matrix Datatype in Swift that can handle complex domains so I have to develop this using Arrays. My algorithm is complete. The only problem I'm facing is the wrong signs in the `V` matrix from SVD. Matlab's SVD's `V` output works great with my developed algorithm but Lapack's SVD's 'V' matrix mess it up due to the wrong signs.

Comment: One thing is that the SVD is not unique. Do the two SVDs both recover the correct matrix?

Comment: @Rammus the results obtained from Matlab's SVD seems to calculate the square root just fine whereas the square root calculated using LAPACK's SVD contains the exact same values but the signs are not right and that causes issues as if I take the square of the computed square root, I'm unable to reproduce the input matrix whereas it works fine in case of Matlab's SVD.

Comment: @Moo I'm not sure about that as I'm weak in Linear Algebra but looking at the question part where I have given both LAPACK's and Matlab's `V` matrix computed by the SVD, can you find a pattern or something?

Comment: So what should I do? How to un-complex-conjugate it :D

Comment: Since a singular matrix $A$ is arbitrarily close to a non-singular matrix, one way to calculate $f(A)$ is by perturbing the matrix and calculating $f(A+E)$ instead, where $E$ is a random matrix with $\|E\| / \|A\|$ on the order of the machine epsilon. This will effectively sidestep the pseudoinverse issue.

Comment: yesterday computed an SVD and then compared my answer vs JMP's ... were identical except one column of V was negative of what I had obtained but that same corresponding row in U was also negative ... to the point that SVD not unique (at least to within sign of individual columns/rows or U/V

Answer (score 1):

Taking the complex conjugate for the matrices U and V resolved the problem for me. I'm able to calculate the Squareroot of the matrix perfectly.